# PWA React cant load page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I create application React JS with `Create React App`. I'm active the PWA service on index.js

```
....
serviceWorker.register();
```

and custom `service-worker.js` on `public` folder like that

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  event.respondWith(async function() {
    try {
      return await fetch(event.request);
    } catch (err) {
      return caches.match(event.request);
    }
  }());
});
```

But my client access my website with `safari browser` get blank white. I think the problem cant render the page. How to solve it? Many thanks.

Comment: Did you configured the "homepage" property in package.json when building your React app?

Comment: If you are deploying your app to root of the domain, you should set "hompage" like this: **"homepage": "."**